# Jupyter notebook presentation - RISE - Aspect Ratio 4:3 on beamer

Tags: python, jupyter, rise

I am preparing a presentation using Jupyter notebook and Rise (for tomorrow). However, the aspect ratio of my laptop is 16:9 and the beamer in the conference room has an aspect ratio of 4:3. I am concerned that the slides with interactive examples (wild mix of Ipython widgets, Plotly, Matplotlib) will look strange, become unusable or unreadable.

The documentation for Rise does not provide any clues. Have you encountered such a setup? Did you observe troubles and how did solve them? E.g. defining the aspect ratio of the plots in beforehand?

Comment: The documentation discusses some settings and suggestions in this regard [here](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize.html#change-the-width-and-height-of-slides).  Most pertinent - "remember that you can always use your browser’s shortcuts to zoom in/out (Cmd/Ctrl + and Cmd/Ctrl -), and this way adjust the slide content to your screen/projector size." AND " In particular it is dangerous to set sizes in pixels, as most often you cannot rehearse with the actual projector."

Comment: I ended up removing the widgets from the slides and opened them in a separate browser tab. Thank you for the link. I wanted to avoid zooming but it was the way to go.